# Add Admob banner to messagekit

Tags: ios, swift, admob, messagekit

how can I add admob banner to messageviewcontroller of messagekit?

I have tried. The ad is loaded but it not visible.

I would like to add the banner to the top of view.

Please help.

```
final class ChatViewController: MessagesViewController, MessagesDataSource {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    messagesCollectionView = MessagesCollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: CustomMessagesFlowLayout())
    messagesCollectionView.register(CustomMessageKitCell.self)
    // In this case, we instantiate the banner with desired ad size.
    bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)

    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-40..."
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.load(GADRequest())
    bannerView.delegate = self
    addBannerViewToView(bannerView)
    ...
}

var bannerView: GADBannerView!

func addBannerViewToView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
 bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 view.addSubview(bannerView)
 view.addConstraints(
   [NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                       attribute: .top,
                       relatedBy: .equal,
                       toItem: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide,
                       attribute: .top,
                       multiplier: 1,
                       constant: 0),
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                       attribute: .centerX,
                       relatedBy: .equal,
                       toItem: view,
                       attribute: .centerX,
                       multiplier: 1,
                       constant: 0)
   ])
}
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `super.viewDidLoad()` *before* you add any subviews (I'm not seeing if you even call it at all but it might be in the `...` at the end). MessageKit uses `viewDidLoad` to add the MessagesCollectionView into the view hierarchy and so if you call `super` after, then your banner view will be underneath the MessagesCollectionView. In this case since you're instantiating a MessagesCollectionView with a custom layout you'll want to call `super` after instantiating that view but before adding any subviews like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    messagesCollectionView = MessagesCollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: CustomMessagesFlowLayout())
    super.viewDidLoad() // <-- Add this
    messagesCollectionView.register(CustomMessageKitCell.self)
    // In this case, we instantiate the banner with desired ad size.
    bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)

    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-40..."
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.load(GADRequest())
    bannerView.delegate = self
    addBannerViewToView(bannerView)
    ...
}
```

Comment: How can I move down the messagesCollectionView, so that the banner doesn't  overlap on it?

Comment: @Pinto Instead of moving the view down it might be easier to set the `contentOffset` with `setContentOffset` on the collectionView to be the height of your banner ad. That should move the scrollable content out of the way of the banner ad

Comment: It doesn't work:   self.messagesCollectionView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 50)

Comment: @Pinto Sorry, I meant `contentInset`. `self.messagesCollectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)` should work. It'll allow you to scroll all the way to the top

Comment: It does move only the bubbles at the beginning. But when we do the scroll down, the banner still overlap the bubble.

Comment: @Pinto You can extend the banner to full width or put the banner inside a full width subview with white bg color or something so that you don't see the overlap. Otherwise if you really want to change the size of the collection view you could try embedding the MessagesViewController as a child view controller and then you could control the size of it on screen. Check out the `MessageContainerController` code in the MessageKit example project to see how to do that. If you need more help after looking at the example code then feel free to open a GitHub issue on the MessageKit repo as well.